# $\lim_{R \to \infty}\int^R_{-R}x^3dx$ implies $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x^3dx$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Does the result of the following calculation:

$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int^R_{-R}x^3dx=\frac{x^4}{4}\Big|^R_{-R}=\frac{1}{4})(R^4-R^4)=0$

Imply that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x^3dx$ exists?

I know that it doesn't but it doesn't really make sense to me. Since $\lim_{x \to 0}0=0$?

**Is there a rigorous proof?**

Comment: @BrickByBrick So what does that imply?

Comment: No.  If the limits exists, it must exist even when the lower bound and the upper bound are going to infinity at different "speeds."  i.e. It must also equal $0$ when $\lim_\limits{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^{2R} f(x) \ dx$ or any other multiple of $R.$ for that matter.

Comment: I prefer writing $\int_{-A}^B f(x)dx$ is finite for $A,B\to \infty$ than with multiples of $R$, I find it shows better the independence of the bounds.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Convergence_of_the_integral) for the conditions for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ to exist. We can't just say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^ndx$ is $0$ ($\infty$) for odd (even) $n\ge0$, because translating $x$ leads to inconsistent results for the integrals of polynomials, e.g. $0=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(y+c)dy=c\cdot\infty$.

Comment: Your argument does not show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3\;dx$ exists.  But it does show that the "Cauchy principal value integral" does exist.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value